# Select using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I saw few examples over internet of Hibernate using `transaction.commit()` for select statements. Below is the example code.

```
public static List<?> list(Class<?> className,int start,int limit,SearchFilter[] searchFilter){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null; 

    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(className);
        criteria.setFirstResult(start);
        criteria.setMaxResults(limit);

        for(SearchFilter sf : searchFilter){
            String[] values = sf.getValue();
            if(values != null){
                if(values.length == 1) {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(sf.getField(), values[0]));
                }else{
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.in(sf.getField(), values));
                }
            }
        }

        List<?> Objects = criteria.list();
        transaction.commit();

        return Objects;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        session.close();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Why do we do beginning and committing a transaction for select statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[everything happens within the scope of a transaction.](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Sessionsandtransactions) sometimes software automatically manages a transaction for you, but hibernate does not. whether read-only or not, [in hibernate you must open and close transactions.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html)

Answer (score 11):

I highly recommend reading [Non-transactional data access and the auto-commit mode](http://community.jboss.org/docs/DOC-13953). Let me quote a small part:

> (...)
>
> Many more issues must be considered
>   when you introduce nontransactional
>   data access in your application. We’ve
>   already noted that introducing a new
>   type of transaction, namely read-only
>   transactions, can significantly
>   complicate any future modification of
>   your application. The same is true if
>   you introduce nontransactional
>   operations.
>
> You would then have three different
>   kinds of data access in your
>   application: in regular transactions,
>   in read-only transactions, and now
>   also nontransactional, with no
>   guarantees. Imagine that you have to
>   introduce an operation that writes
>   data into a unit of work that was
>   supposed to only read data. Imagine
>   that you have to reorganize operations
>   that were nontransactional to be
>   transactional.
>
> Our recommendation is to not use the
>   autocommit mode in an application, and
>   to **apply read-only transactions only
>   when there is an obvious performance
>   benefit** or when future code changes
>   are highly unlikely. Always prefer
>   regular ACID transactions to group
>   your data-access operations,
>   regardless of whether you read or
>   write data.
>
> Having said that, Hibernate and Java
>   Persistence allow nontransactional
>   data access. In fact, the EJB 3.0
>   specification forces you to access
>   data nontransactionally if you want to
>   implement atomic long-running
>   conversations. We’ll approach this
>   subject in the next chapter. Now we
>   want to dig a little deeper into the
>   consequences of the autocommit mode in
>   a plain Hibernate application. (Note
>   that, despite our negative remarks,
>   there are some good use cases for the
>   autocommit mode. In our experience
>   autocommit is often enabled for the
>   wrong reasons and we wanted to wipe
>   the slate clean first.)
>
> #### Working nontransactionally with Hibernate
>
> Look at the following code, which
>   accesses the database without
>   transaction boundaries:
>
> ```
> Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(); 
> session.get(Item.class, 123l); 
> session.close();
> ```
>
> By default, in a Java SE environment
>   with a JDBC configuration, this is
>   what happens if you execute this
>   snippet:
>
> 1. A new Session is opened. It doesn’t obtain a database connection at this
>      point.
> 2. The call to get() triggers an SQL SELECT. The Session now obtains a JDBC
>      Connection from the connection pool.
>      Hibernate, by default, immediately
>      turns off the autocommit mode on this
>      connection with setAutoCommit(false).
>      This effectively starts a JDBC
>      transaction!
> 3. The SELECT is executed inside this JDBC transaction. The Session is
>      closed, and the connection is returned
>      to the pool and released by Hibernate
>      — Hibernate calls close() on the JDBC
>      Connection. What happens to the
>      uncommitted transaction?
>
> The answer to that question is, “It
>   depends!” The JDBC specification
>   doesn’t say anything about pending
>   transactions when close() is called on
>   a connection. What happens depends on
>   how the vendors implement the
>   specification. With Oracle JDBC
>   drivers, for example, the call to
>   close() commits the transaction! Most
>   other JDBC vendors take the sane route
>   and roll back any pending transaction
>   when the JDBC Connection object is
>   closed and the resource is returned to
>   the pool.
>   Obviously, this won’t be a problem for the SELECT you’ve executed (...)

Answer (score 0):

Well the commit is actually useless, but, as psanton said, everything happens within the scope of a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your operations in transactions even for selects due to isolation levels and repeatable reads encountered when you use MySQL's InnoDB engine.

Check out the issue that I faced here.

[Hibernate collection not updated when records inserted externally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119184/hibernate-collection-not-updated-when-records-inserted-externally/6133211)