# HibernateTemplate fall back to auto-commit, where?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

HibernateTemplate api says:

> *...its capability to fall back to 'auto-commit' style behavior when used outside of transactions*

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html

Can anyone please point out where that happens:

[https://github.com/](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/dd2bf28a4f2c20cc6510266f245c619755e851ba/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.java)

[http://grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-orm/3.2.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.java#HibernateTemplate)

I searched for like an hour with no success. I'm looking for the answer for when transactions are created in my app, as I understand hibernate demands a transaction to be open for every interaction with db but I don't open any transaction neither I use JTA and I still have reading operations working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[All database statements are executed within the context of a physical transaction](http://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/), even when we don’t explicitly declare transaction boundaries (BEGIN/COMMIT/ROLLBACK). Data integrity is enforced by the [ACID properties of database transactions](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-acid-and-database-transactions/).

So if you don't enrol your current unit of work in the context of a logical transaction (Spring transaction interceptor), then each DB statement will execute in a separate database physical transaction, hence you are going to run in "auto-commit" mode.

> ...its capability to fall back to 'auto-commit' style behavior when
>   used outside of transactions

This phrase tell you that you can use TransactionTemplate from within a @Transactional context and even without a transaction context as well. So you are not obliged to use the Spring transaction demarcation, although [for performance reasons you should do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327274/do-you-need-transaction-for-reading-data/26327536#26327536).

So your TransactionTemplate related code works independently of having or not having a currently running transaction context.

With plain-old JDBC your code must explicitly declare a transaction boundary (begin/commit/rollback) if you want to enroll multiple statements in a single database transaction. If you don't do that you will run in "auto-commit" mode.

Comment: So what then "..as well as its capability to fall back to 'auto-commit'." means? If we can achieve that with no effort anyway, what does the api docs says? Does spring do something about it to fall back or not?

Comment: So you say we you are not obliged to open transaction from the client code at all. I mean we should but it won't throw any exception if we don't. I was confused with hibernate docs saying "Database, or system, transaction boundaries are always necessary." [http://docs.jboss.org](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation) I want to try to work with hibernate it outside of spring if it works without exceptions I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Of course it works. Why to you think there's a Hibernate property such as [hibernate.connection.autocommit](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-jdbc-properties).