# Commit transaction immideatly after method finished

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have the following problem:

I'm using Spring MVC 4.0.5 with Hibernate 4.3.5 and I'm trying to create a Restfull Web application. The problem is that I want to exclude some fields from getting serialized as JSON, depending on the method called in the controller using aspects.

My problem now is that Hiberate does not commit the transaction immideatly after it returns from a method but just before serializing.

Controller.java

```
public class LoginController {
    /*
     *  Autowire all the Services and stuff..
     */
    @RemoveAttribues({"fieldA","fieldB"})
    @RequestMapping{....}
    public ResponseEntity login(@RequestBody user) {
        User updatedUser = userService.loginTheUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(updatedUser,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Service.java

```
public class UserService {
    @Transactional
    public User loginUser(User user) {
        user.setLoginToken("some generated token");
        return userDao.update(user); //userDao just calls entityManager.merge(..)
    }
}
```

The advice of the aspect does the following:

```
for every String find the corresponding setter and set the field to null
```

This is done, like I said, to avoid serialization of data (for which Jackson 2 is used)

The problem now is that only after the advice has finished the transaction is commited. Is there anything I can do to tell hibernate to commit immediatly or do I have to dig deeper and start handling the transactions myself (which I would like to avoid)?

EDIT:
I also have autocommit turned on

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
```

I think the problem lies in the fact that I use lazy loading (because each user may have a huge laod of other enities attached to him), so the transaction is not commited until I try to serialze the object.

Comment: using transactions, but with autocommit on?? O_o

Comment: I do have autocommit turned on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't set auto-commit to true. [It's a terrible mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327274/do-you-need-transaction-for-reading-data/26327536#26327536).

I think you need a `UserService` interface and a `UserServiceImpl` for the interface implementation. Whatever you now have in the `UserService` class must be migrated to `UserServiceImpl` instead.

This can ensure that the `@Transactions` are applied even for `JDK` dynamic proxies and not just for `CGLIB` runtime proxies.

If you are using `Open-Session-in-View` anti-patterns, you need to let it go and [use session-per-request instead](http://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/). It's much more scalable and it forces you to handle optimum queries sin your data layer.

Using [JDBC Transaction Management and the default `session-close-on-request pattern`](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/) you should be fine with this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did have PersistenceContext.EXTENDED turned on and it did solve my problem turning it off.