# JPA sql server 'nolock' without transaction

Tags: sql-server, jpa, nolock

I searched for ways to query `with nolock` from JPA, but I get errors saying I'm not in a transaction, which is `true`. Is it possible to turn off locking without a transaction?

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327274/do-you-need-a-database-transaction-for-reading-data/26327536

Comment: I don't think the nolock hint does what you think it does. It does not prevent all locking. And honestly you probably really don't want to query with nolock. Unless you are ok with mostly accurate results most of the time you should avoid this. Here is a great article on the topic. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/