# how to use HibernateTemplate.find() for and operator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to `Hibernate` and `Spring`. I want to retrieve data from HQL query made by `HibernateTemplate.find()`. This query has a `and` operator.

When I reference a `List` with HibernateTemplate.find(), List size comes out to be 0. Below is my code.

```
public long getMetaDataID(String customerID,String objectID){
        long metadataID=0;
        long customerID_l=Long.parseLong(customerID);
        long objectID_l=Long.parseLong(objectID);
        List<RWFieldMetadata> list =template.find("from RWFieldMetadata p where p.customer_id = ? and p.object_id=?", customerID_l,objectID_l);
        for(RWFieldMetadata obj: list){
            metadataID=obj.getId();
        }
        return metadataID;
    }
```

I know there is a `criteria` also. But I find it difficult and want to keep using `HibernateTemplate.find()`. Why am I getting list size as 0. What error am I committing here.

Comment: Have you checked the Parameter?

Comment: yes, they are coming. But still list size is 0

Comment: Add your `RWFieldMetadata` class.

Comment: @M.Deinum where should I add.

Comment: Can you Check it by writing your hql query like this.                                           template.find("from RWFieldMetadata p where p.customer_id = ? and p.object_id=?").setInt(customerID_1).setInt(objectID_1);

Answer (score -1):

Usually if you get an empty list it means that you don't use a transaction. `HibernateTemplate` doesn't create a transaction itself. You need a transaction not only to write data, but to read it too.

You need to add a transaction to the `getMetaDataID()` method. You can do it with the `@Transactional` annotation, but you need get your class from a spring context.

You can open a transaction using `session.beginTransaction()` too but you need to properly control it.

Comment: No you don't, for reading you don't need a transaction. Next to that the template actually uses a local tx when there is no tx.

Comment: @M.Deinum Please, show where in the source a transaction is created [HibernateTemplate#doExecute()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTemplate.java#HibernateTemplate.doExecute%28org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateCallback%2Cboolean%29). A transaction is really [need](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3713847/3405171) for reading data.

Comment: @M.Deinum And where get a local tx in the console application, for an example?

Comment: NO you don't need a transaction for reading data, writing is a different beast.